# Function filter() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I study jquery, but i have a little confusion about this code :

```
var list = mylist.filter(function(f) {
    return $(f)
        .find('.anthing')
        .length > 0;
});
```

what does $(f) mean?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: points to `mylist` element

Comment: filter method loop through all elements in array and give you callback for each item to test, that callback parameter is item in the array

Comment: What is `mylist` ? An `array` or `jQuery-object` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `mylist` is an `array` or `array like` object. The `f` in the parameters is the single item in your `myList`.It calls the function for every item in the `myList`.Then it wraps your `f` into `jQuery` object and then the `.find()` will be visible on your object

Comment: OP is asking what is __`f`__

Comment: @Rayon He asks `$(f)` not `f`

Comment: Isn't `f` part of `$(f)` ?

Comment: I can know what is `f` but not what is `$(f)`

Answer (score 0):

> It is the index passed through the function, which indicates the
>   0-based position of the element within the unfiltered set of matched
>   elements.

In your case `$(f)` is useless since it represent `$(0) || $(1)` which does not represent a selection.